# How to close google-font reference in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-font-api

I'm a Chinese user, using WordPress(3.9.1) to built several websites.

But current days the website (both the frontend pages and the wordpress admin pages) goes extremely slow.

After checking the requests, I found the requests to the google-font link always fail. Maybe caused by the Chinese GFW.

The google-font API requests follows:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&ver=3.9.1

But fails, the delay may cause the entire page cannot finish loading!

And this was automatically injected to both the admin html and client theme html. How to close that entirely? Or at least prevent the delay for such a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is **simply** install the plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-google-fonts/

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use this wordpress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-google-fonts-references/

This plugin disable all google font.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this in your stylesheet:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```

If you find that, you can delete it. But you will want to replace `font-family:'Open Sans'` with the simpler `font-family:sans-serif` elsewhere in your stylesheet.

If you do not find the `@import` line, someone may have buried this one in your theme's header:

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

If so, same drill -- you may remove it, but you'll want to also remove references to `'Open Sans'` in your stylesheet.

Comment: The point is that WordPress kernel code imports the Google-font api. I want to remove it outside the kernel code. For example using some hook functions.